# Realm Swift not working after app enters foreground from background

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm working on a project that involves two applications communicating with each other. The problem is when one or both applications become idle for sometime (enters background), and then becomes active (enters foreground), when I perform functions that involve Realm execution (ie realm.write()), the changes are not reflected right away. Sometimes i need to restart the application, then after restarting, the execution will proceed (automatic).

I tried refreshing the view controllers but realm functions still dont work in real time until after restarting. Now im not sure if there's a realm configuration for this, or ios issue.
I already tried reconfiguring realm sync after return to foreground, but transaction still only proceeds after restarting, or has a long delay.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    MyAPI.sharedInstance.realmConfig() }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may wish to reassign your realm instance when app enters foreground by realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance() and then proceed to write anything you want.

Comment: already did something like this 
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        MyAPI.sharedInstance.realmConfig()
}
but still transactions proceed only after restarting, or has a long delay.

Comment: Can you please provide more specific information about the problem you're seeing? You say that "changes are not reflected right away". What do you mean by that? What steps have you taken to try to understand why you're seeing this problem? Have you added additional logging to determine where any delay is coming from? Have you looked at Instruments to see where CPU time is being spent during the delay?

Comment: Ive figured out by checking the realm browser, that write transactions are not executed right away after .write() but im getting no errors. I believe this is a realm feature to save changes locally first, then sync when connection is restored (i believe the culprit is the connection). Now i need to handle this by knowing if there's a way in realmswift to know if changes are saved locally and not yet synced to the object server?

Comment: You can get the date is synced or not by using sync progress notifications, see https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#progress-notifications